# How to get data to js from JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a problem and I wonder could anyone help me. In a result I want to make some small maps with a different GPS track on them. But I have a problem with getting data. I need to get GPS track from a server. Then extract coordinates of all dots which belong to this track and put this data in js(on the map). I'll show:
Here I have a controller:

```
@Controller
public class TracksGeopointsController {

    @Autowired
    private IndexGeopointsService indexGeopointsService;
    @Autowired
    private TracksGeopointsService tracksGeopointsService;
    @Autowired
    private FileService fileService;
    @Autowired
    private MySaxParser mySaxParser;

    @RequestMapping(value = TracksGeopointsRoutes.TRACKS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String tracks(Model model){

        List<TracksGeopointsDoc> tracks = tracksGeopointsService.findAllTracks();
        Map<ObjectId, List<DotGeopointsDoc>> dotsMap = new HashMap<ObjectId, List<DotGeopointsDoc>>();
        for (TracksGeopointsDoc track : tracks){

            try {
                List<DotGeopointsDoc> dots = tracksGeopointsService.getAllTrackDots(track.getId());
                dotsMap.put(track.getId(), dots);
                model.addAttribute("dotsMap", dotsMap); //here I put data to a model to transport it to JSP
                model.addAttribute("tracks", tracks); //here I put data to a model to transport it to JSP
            } catch (TrackNotExistException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        Breadcrumbs breadcrumbs = indexGeopointsService.breadcrumbs();
        breadcrumbs.setCurrentPageTitle("GPS треки");

        model.addAttribute("breadcrumbs", breadcrumbs);

        return "com.ub.geopoints_test.tracks";

    }
}
```

And my JSP looks like that:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <c:forEach var="track" items="${tracks}" varStatus="count"> //I know how to extract data from model above - ${tracks}
            <script>
                var map = L.map('map');
                // create the tile layer with correct attribution
                var osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
                var osmAttrib='Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
                var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 1, maxZoom: 12, attribution: osmAttrib});

                map.addLayer(osm);
                L.Routing.control({
                 waypoints: [

                 L.latLng(57.74, 11.94), // here I want to put data that I gave to model. If it was not js, I'll do this: L.latLng(${dotsMap.get(track.id).lat}, ${dotsMap.get(track.id).lat}) But I don't know how can I do it with js
                 L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949),
                 L.latLng(57.65, 11.888)
                 ]
                 }).addTo(map);
            </script>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please, could anyone help me. I really don't know how I can do it.

Comment: Please clear the point, From `L.latLng(57.74, 11.94)` this line you need to call your controller. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. From this line I need to get data that I'm passing with my controller.

Comment: You can send your request via [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and get the response.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan — Why make extra HTTP requests and have to preserve state across them?

Comment: "If it was not js, I'll do this: L.latLng(${dotsMap.get(track.id).lat}, ${dotsMap.get(track.id).lat})" — Have you tried that? What output did you get? Does JSP actually care that you are outputting JS instead of HTML? As far as most template languages are concerned, text is text and it doesn't matter what the browser is parsing it as.

Comment: var dots = ${dotsMap.get(track.id)}. Here I get a List of objects. If I do that I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same jsp page if you write js code you can store model value in java script variable.
For example :

`var varName = ${modelName.variableName}`

So you can render any model value in the javascript code block in the same jsp.

Comment: var dots = ${dotsMap.get(track.id)}. Here I get a List of objects. If I do that I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: I guess it is not proper way to get map value in jsp page. You can try using - <c:out value="${dotsMap[track.id]}"/>

Comment: I tried <c:set var="d" value="${dotsMap[track.id]}"/>. But when I tried to get the value of "d" in js - var dots = ${d}; "dots" contains this: var dots = [geopoints_test.dots.models.DotGeopointsDoc@49e58a0e, geopoints_test.dots.models.DotGeopointsDoc@7ccac308, geopoints_test.dots.models.DotGeopointsDoc@63ca8239, geopoints_test.dots.models.DotGeopointsDoc@42b9f5e, geopoints_test.dots.models.DotGeopointsDoc@4bebd675, ...]; And I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. How can I fix it?

Comment: It happens because the full java object is stored in js variable. You need to store primitive type field value in js variable to use it. You can do it like ${d.fieldName} or ${dotsMap[track.id].fieldName}

Comment: Thanks for your answer it've lead me to the right solution. Thanks a lot.